# Dictionary<T,Delegate> with Delegates of different types: Cleaner, non string method names?

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, methods, delegates

There has to be a cleaner method. Currently I have:

```
... Constructor()
{
      parseDictionary = new Dictionary<typeOfStream, Delegate>()
            {
                {typeOfStream.SOME_ENUM_VAL, Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(ParseDelegate<string>), this, "MyMethod")},
                {typeOfStream.SOME_OTHER_ENUM_VAL, Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(ParseDelegate<XmlNode>), this, "MyOtherMethod")}
            };
}

public bool MyMethod(string some_string)
{
    ...
}

public bool MyOtherMethod(XmlNode some_node)
{
    ...
}
```

and I would like to get rid of *"MyMethod"* and *MyOtherMethod* and make it *this.MyMethod* and *this.MyOtherMethod*. Options?

I am open to any solution that allows me to use a Dictionary lookup, and point my data mojo into an arbitrary method (well a defined method with an arbitrary bunch of arguments) for parsing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just cast to the right kind of delegate:

```
parseDictionary = new Dictionary<typeOfStream, Delegate>()
{
    { typeOfStream.SOME_ENUM_VAL, (ParseDelegate<string>) MyMethod) },
    { typeOfStream.SOME_OTHER_ENUM_VAL, (ParseDelegate<XmlNode>) MyOtherMethod }
};
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `<typeOfStream, ParseDelegate>` ?

Comment: Perfect. I had no idea you could cast to a delegate. Opens up a whole new world of possibilities!